# Hide paging toolbar for Tree Grid

Tags: rally, treegrid, pagingtoolbar

Is the showPagingToolbar config option available for the rallytreegrid?  This config option is listed for the rallygrid xtype but does not seem to work for the rallytreegrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like that config exists, you're right.  You should be able to work around it by hiding it once the grid is rendered.

Simply add the following event listeners config to your existing config when creating your treegrid:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(treegrid) {
        treegrid.down('#pagingToolbar').hide();
    }
}
```